# Getting user input doesn't work correctly

Tags: c

I am writing a simple program in C using structs. The user needs to enter some values for the struct - a name and age. After I enter the data for the first time, the second time the program just skips one of the fields and only wants me to enter the second field of the data. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
    struct Person {

        char name[20];
        int age;
    };

void main(){

    struct Person pArray[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Please enter a name and age:\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        fgets(pArray[i].name, 20, stdin);
        printf("Age: ");
        scanf("%d", &pArray[i].age);
    }
}
```

As you can see, after entering Jonathan and 45 for the first time, the second time it skipped the name and wants only the age. Why is this happening?
[image]

Comment: `scanf("%d", &pArray[i].age);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &pArray[i].age);`

Comment: You need to consume the newline after the `age` input.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, so adding '%*c' like Sourav Ghosh suggested will consume the line?

Comment: It consumes the newline character OR any other character following the number, so it isn't a robust solution, just a quick fix

Comment: You might want to read my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: Or just `scanf("%d ");` - whitespace is hardly significant in a name, and empty names usually don't exist either.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala-- except that with a trailing whitespace, `scanf()` will wait for a non-whitespace character before returning, causing unexpected behavior in many circumstances.

Comment: @FelixPalmen thanks, I read you guide  and I have a question. If I use fgets and I want to get rid of the '\n' instead of strcspn, can I use something like `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';` or is it a bad approach?

Comment: @Keselme-- this approach leads to undefined behavior if `buffer` is an empty string, but should work for a successfully obtained `fgets()` string, which should at least contain the `'\n'` character before the null terminator. A better approach is to use `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = '\0';`. Or, alternatively, something like `char *ptr; if ((ptr = strchr(buffer, '\n')) != NULL) { *ptr = '\0'; }`

Comment: Well, I used strcspn() but I still get the same result on the second entry I still skip the name field.

Comment: @Keselme-- That is because `scanf()` leaves a newlline in the input stream, and this is interfering with `fgets()`. You can do as [SouravGhosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377459/getting-user-input-doesnt-work-correctly#comment77716432_45377459) suggests, or even better don't use `scanf()` at all. Stick to `fgets()`, reading all user input into a buffer array, and using `sscanf()` to parse the buffer if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I try not to mix formatted and unformatted input (e.g., `fgets` and `scanf`). Here is your program using only `fgets` for input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Person {
    char name[20];
    int age;
};

int main(){
    struct Person pArray[10];
    char numberBuffer[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Please enter a name and age:\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        fgets(pArray[i].name, 20, stdin);
        printf("Age: ");
        fgets(numberBuffer, 20, stdin);
        sscanf(numberBuffer, "%d", &pArray[i].age);
    }
}
```